# What are the approaches and trade-offs involved in a platform-independent representation?

Tags: c++, c, performance, compatibility

Before saying anything I have to say that, albeit I'm an experienced programmer in Java, I'm rather new to C / C++ programming.

I have to save a binary file in a format that makes it accessible from different operating systems & platforms. It should be very efficient because I have to deal with a lot of data. What approaches should I investigate for that?  What are the main advantages and disadvantages?

Currently I'm thinking about using the network notation (something like `htonl` that is available both under [unix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/htonl.html) and [windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ). Is there a better way?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a Research Assistant - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/139168

Comment: @0A0D, this question is fine.  He's asking a specific question about "actual problems that [he] faces", and the mention of `htonl` shows he has already done research.

Comment: I asked for [feedback](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136765/is-this-question-constructive) on this on meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are a couple of decent choices for this kind of task.

In most cases, my first choice would probably be Sun's (now Oracle's) XDR. It's used in Sun's implementation of RPC, so it's been pretty heavily tested for quite a while. It's defined in [RFC 1832](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1832.txt), so documentation is widely available. There are also [libraries](http://xstream.sourceforge.net/) (portable and [otherwise](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xdr)) that know how to convert to/from this format. On-wire representation is reasonably compact and conversion fairly efficient.

The big potential problem with XDR is that you do need to know what the data represents to decode it -- i.e., you have to (by some outside means) ensure that the sender and receiver agree on (for example) the definition of the structs they'll send over the wire, before the receiver can (easily) understand what's being sent.

If you need to create a stream that's entirely self-describing, so somebody can figure out what it contains based only on the content of the stream itself, then you might consider ASN.1. It's crufty and nasty in some ways, but it does produce self-describing streams, is publicly documented, and it's used pretty widely (though mostly in rather limited domains). There are a fair number of libraries that implement encoding and decoding. I doubt anybody really likes it much, but if you need what it does, it's probably the first choice, if only because it's already known and somewhat accepted.

Comment: XDR seems to be really close to our (buggy) current implementation of the serializantion/deserialization. We do have an upper-level protocol that describes the structure of the data, and we use that to drive the reading process (currently we read integers/doubles/strings/arrays directly from the file). Hence I think that XDR is exactly what we need.

Answer (score 6):

[Network order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_order#Endianness_in_networking) (big-endian) is something of a de facto standard.  However, if your program will be used mostly on [x86](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) (which is little-endian), you may want to stick with that for performance reasons (the protocol will still be usable on big-endian machines, but they will instead have the performance impact).

Besides [htonl](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/htonl.html) (which converts 32-bit values), there's also htons (16-bit), and bswap_64 (non-standard for 64-bit).

If you want a binary format, but you'd like to abstract away some of the details to ease serialization and deserialization, consider [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) or [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/).  Protocol Buffers are updatable (you can add optional or repeated (0 or more) fields to the schema without breaking existing code); not sure about Thrift.

However, before premature optimization, consider whether parsing is really the bottleneck.  If reading every line of the file will require a database query or calculation, you may be able to use a more readable format without any noticeable performance impact.

Comment: +1 from me as well.  I don't know much on the subject, but I don't see anything obviously wrong here, and no explanation of why this is a poor answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Since my application will be supported only/mainly on x86 architectures, I'd like to avoid the continuous conversion between big-endian and little-endian. For this reason, I do not follow my initial plan of using the network convention (i.e., methods hton* and ntoh*). Indeed, this part of the application is used both for writing files (where an optimization has a negligible impact on performances) and as neutral convention to store data in a shared memory. The latter requires us to be efficient, and this is why I'll investigate the topic furthermore.

Comment: @Matteo, so you're using shared memory for inter-process communication?  That could easily be its own question, and using the same format for both may not be the right decision.

Answer (score 0):

My first choice for a situation like this would be ASN.1 since it gives you the flexibility of using whatever programing language you desire on either end, as well as being platform independent.  It hides the endian-ness issues from you so you don't have to worry about them.  One end can use Java while the other end uses C or C++ or C#.  It also supports multiple encoding rules you can chose from depending on your needs.  There is PER (Packed Encoding Rules) if the goal is making the encoding as small as possible, or there is E-XER (Extended XML Encoding Rules) if you prefer to exchange information using XML, or there is DER (Distingushed Encoding Rules) if your application involves digital signatures or certificates.  ASN.1 is widely used in telephony, but also used in banking, automobiles, aviation, medical devices, and several other area.  It is mature proven technology that has stood the test of time and continues to be added in new areas where communication between disparate machines and programming languages is needed.

An excellent resource where you can try ASN.1 free is http://asn1-playground.oss.com where you can play with some existing ASN.1 specifications, or try creating your own, and see what the various encoding rules produce.

There are some excellent books available as a free download from http://www.oss.com/asn1/resources/books-whitepapers-pubs/asn1-books.html where the first one is titled "ASN.1 — Communication Between Heterogeneous Systems".